# I am looking for the command in a program that filters only when 3 letters are entered

Tags: vue.js, filter, searchbar, .when

I am looking for the command in a program that filters only when 3 letters are entered. Does anyone know what command or code I need to look for to find this?

Maybe it's also a Vue-Command, because my program is written in Vue.js.

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to do? You'll need to explain/show your code and what you've tried to get something working.

Comment: I want to change a filter, so you can search something but the filter only filters when you have typed at least 3 letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the search input to a function first then validate the input. If passes the validation, proceed with searching.

Assuming this is your search input

```
<input v-model="searchInput"/>
```

Add an input event handler

```
<input v-model="searchFor" @input="searchHandler"/>
```

Then validate the search input with searchHandler method

```
new Vue({

  methods: {
    searchHandler (text) {
      if(text.length > 2){
      // Write your code on here
      }
    }
  }
```

})

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of debouncing to perform some functionality after some time, here you can also add a condition to check for the length of the input and then execute the logic.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("myInput");

function callApi() {
    if(input.value.length >= 3) {
        console.log("Hello JS")
    }
}

function debounce( callback, d ) {
    let timeout;
    return function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout( callback, d );
    }
}

myInput.addEventListener(
    "keyup",
    debounce(callApi, 500 )
);
```

```html
<label for="myInput">Type something in!</label>
<input id="myInput" type="text">
```